# How should I put limit inside for loop using if condition using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My goal is that only 15 quantities of input elements can be accepted, once the user enters 16  it should say that only 15 input elements is allowed. However I don't know how will I do this. I tried putting condition inside for but it is not not working. I am a little bit confused on this

Here is my HTML code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label> Quantity: </label>
    <input class="form-control" name="quantity" type="number" id="get_Elem"
     required>
     <br>
    <input type="button" id="sb_add_ctrl" name="is_Sub" class="btn btn- 
     primary" value="Add Control Number">
</div>
<div class="form-group" name="parent" id="parent"></div>
```

Here is my JS code

```
$(document).on('click', '#sb_add_ctrl', function() {
var element = $('#get_Elem').val();
var input;
var parent = $(document.getElementById("parent"));
var value = $('#sel_control_num').val();

functionPopulate(parent);

if (isNaN(element)) {
    return;
}

for (var i = 0; i < element; i++) {
    
    if(should I do it here??){

    }

    value = value.replace(/(\d+)$/, function(match, element) {
        const nextValue = ++match;
        return ('0' + nextValue).slice(1);
    });


    document.getElementById("parent").style.padding = "5px 0px 0px 0px";
    document.getElementById("parent").innerHTML += '<br><input type="text" 
    value="' + value +
        '" class="form-control" name="get_Input_show[]" required>'

  }
});
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65803309/edit) to include your HTML.

Comment: @kmoser done editting sir.

Comment: please Take a look at this https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp

Comment: Yeah that is what I've tried but when I clicked the button it will add another 15, it won't break :(

Comment: I think putting this before loop will work. if(element>15){alert("error");}

Comment: Thanks @ManthanTripathi but still the same, yeah it alerts that it is exceeding to 15 but when I clicked the button again it adds another 15 but alerts exceeding 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the `element` value is `< 16` if yes then only add html else show error message.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).on('click', '#sb_add_ctrl', function() {
  var element = $('#get_Elem').val();
  var input;
  //var value = $('#sel_control_num').val();
  var value = 12;
  //functionPopulate(parent);
  if (isNaN(element)) {
    return;
  }
  //check if elemnt value if < 16
  if (element < 16) {
    $("#parent").empty() //empty div
    for (var i = 0; i < element; i++) {

      /* value = value.replace(/(\d+)$/, function(match, element) {
         const nextValue = ++match;
         return ('0' + nextValue).slice(1);
       });*/


      document.getElementById("parent").style.padding = "5px 0px 0px 0px";
      document.getElementById("parent").innerHTML += '<br><input type="text"  value = "' + value + '" class="form-control" name="get_Input_show[]" required>';

    }
  } else {

    alert("only 15") //show error
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label> Quantity: </label>
  <input class="form-control" name="quantity" type="number" id="get_Elem" required>
  <br>
  <input type="button" id="sb_add_ctrl" name="is_Sub" class="btn btn- 
     primary" value="Add Control Number">
</div>
<div class="form-group" name="parent" id="parent"></div>
```

Comment: Your welcome :) .Also , you can empty your `parent` div using `$("#parent").empty()` before appending new values added that as well in my answer.

Comment: I see what you did there :D

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways in which you can restrict it

1. You can use [maxLength](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp) property of an input tag, which will restrict the user to input the 16th character.
2. You can keep checking the value in the input field and show error if the length is more than 15 character. To do this you can use `onkeypress` event on input, like

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="test" onkeypress="test()" />
```

JS:

```
<script>
  function test() {
    alert('Hi')
  }
</script>
```